# Cannot read property 'contains' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a react based app with a dropdown menu, this dropdown works as a navigation. What I have to achieve is that when I click outside the dropdown the dropdown should be closed. I tried using useEffect and useRef. Here is my code:

```
  useEffect( () => {
    const onClickOutsideNavbar = (event) => {
      if (ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
        return
      };

      setNavItemsOpen(false);
    };

    document.body.addEventListener("click", onClickOutsideNavbar)

    return () => {
      document.body.removeEventListener("click", onClickOutsideNavbar);
    }
  }, [])
```

My JSX has a li which renders each **nav item** and an **ul** as a parent also a **button** which is used to trigger the dropdown and a **div** which hold all of this.

Everything was working until I added react-router-dom to link my pages.

```
<div ref= {ref}>
  <button onClick={handleNavToggle}>Trigger</button>
  <ul>
    <Link to="/navitem"><li>Nav Item</li></Link>
    <Link to=""><li>Nav Item</li></Link>
    <Link to=""><li>Nav Item</li></Link>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Whenever I click on 2nd or 3rd link, nothing happens. But if I click on the first link which will take me to **NavItem**, then my react app crashes after showing the new component for 1 sec.
The error is

> Cannot read property 'contains' of null.

If anyone know the reason behind this error please explain it to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your `ref` might be `undefined` after change to new page. So `contains` method is `null`. I don't have enough information to conclude but you can use ? operator to prevent app crash.

```
if (ref?.current?.contains(event.target)) {
        return
      };
```

Comment: Yeah.. I did the same. I understood that is because my ref changed to undefined, but how, that's what I was wondering.. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Nijesh Because the onclickoutside function is attaching a click event listener to the window and the document in general, not the react component, so when you're navigating other pages or other components, the ref may be undefiend or null because the compnent isn't rendered, yet the event listener is still listening to click events produced by any click inside the doc that bubbles up (general behavior of click event).